# How to check the color of pixels inside a polygon and remove the polygon if it contains white pixels using python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a polygon say,

```
polyg = np.array([[[247,358],[247,361],[260,361],[268,362],[288,363],[303,365],[314,365],[315,364],[247,358]]],np.int32)
```

I want to determine the color of pixels inside this polygon and if it has more than 5 white pixels the polygon should be removed from the image.

Can anyone help me out. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV. **However, I am not sure what you mean by "removing" the polygon.** In the following, I make the polygon region black.

- Read the input
- Convert it to gray
- Define the polygon vertices
- Create a mask for the polygon
- Get the pixel colors from the gray image where the mask is 255
- Count the number of white ones
- If the count is greater than 5, make the polygon region in the input image black; otherwise leave it alone
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('barn.png')

# convert image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# define polygon points
points = np.array( [[[200,0],[230,0],[230,30],[200,30]]], dtype=np.int32 )

# draw polygon on input to visualize
img_poly = img.copy()
cv2.polylines(img_poly, [points], True, (0,0,255), 1)

# create mask for polygon
mask = np.zeros_like(gray)
cv2.fillPoly(mask,[points],(255))

# get color values in gray image corresponding to where mask is white
values = gray[np.where(mask == 255)]

# count number of white values
count = 0
for value in values:
    if value == 255:
        count = count + 1
print("count =",count)

if count > 5:
    result = img.copy()
    result[mask==255] = (0,0,0)
else:
    result = img


# save results
cv2.imwrite('barn_polygon.png', img_poly)
cv2.imwrite('barn_mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('barn_poly_result.png', result)

cv2.imshow('barn_poly', img_poly)
cv2.imshow('barn_mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('barn_result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Input showing red polygon (just a square):

[image]

Mask:

[image]

Reported Count:

```
count = 36
```

Resulting Image with polygon blackened:

[image]